# coerce() equivalent in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

`coerce()` function which

> returns a tuple consisting of the two numeric arguments converted to a
>   common type, using the same rules as used by arithmetic operations

is deprecated in Python 3. I would like to know if there are any equivalent functions introduced in Python 3.x?

Comment: http://python3porting.com/differences.html#coerce-and-coerce

Comment: I guess the loss of relevance comes largely from dropping the separate `long` type.

Comment: As explained in my answer, arithmetic since pep-3141 back in 2007 has handled this for you, so coerce should only be used in code for python versions < 2.6, which means only unsupported python versions have any use for coerce.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even if it's no longer needed (and thus you also should not use this if you're not working on legacy code) you can just do:

```
def coerce(x, y):
    t = type(x + y)
    return (t(x), t(y))
```

Comment: I appreciate that this is the literal answer, but isn't the most correct answer "don't"?

Comment: He didn't specify the use-case, for example you could have a Python 2 library that you want to convert.

Comment: In which case surely the conversion would be to remove usage of coerce, which hasn't been useful in python 2 for some time?

Comment: Could be a lot of annoying find-replace. Also, what do you do if `coerce` was abused to guess a common serialization type or something? Of course, the OP's comment to the other answer renders this discussion moot, but there are IMHO legitimate use-cases for a replacement function.

Comment: I guess, but would you mind editing your answer to reflect that you probably don't want to do this, seeing as it is now the accepted answer so will get more eyes?

Answer (score 2):

The reason for `coerce()` being removed in python 3 is that it is no longer relevant, please see http://python3porting.com/differences.html#coerce-and-coerce

You are expected to be able to just use arithmetic operators without coercion, and it is expected that you should be explicit when formatting output for display. This has been the case since pep-3141 back in 2007, which was already implemented in python 2.6, the oldest supported language version.

I would be tempted to be more militant than the accepted answer in saying that you really shouldn't be trying to do this. To rely on python versions that this would break, will simple hurt you in many other ways.

Comment: I'm just studying the 2to3 conversion, and found this deprecated function. anyway 2 + 2.0 gives you 4.0 (python will convert it to a common type without coerce).